# Wifi problem on asus UX303U 4G working but not wifi

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 16.04

I installed ubuntu 16.04 lts on my asus UX303U and the wifi is perfectly working on windows 10 and also working on Ubuntu with 4G but wifi is not working do you have any idea what could cause the problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Jonathan

EDIT :

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    3: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT n°2

```
[    2.029040] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.044748] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.044774] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.044789] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.052157] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.094259] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    2.094745] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.095464] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.166187] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.169526] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.102491] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.103261] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.165151] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.165599] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   53.336123] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I see no problems here. Can you also add the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`?

Comment: anything wrong ?

Comment: All looks OK with the drivers. It should work.